# How to get the first item of a tuple of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a tuple of tuples right here, how can I get a list of the first item in each tuple?
For example a list of Beverages, Hot Apps, Cold Apps, etc.

```
CATEGORIES = (
        ('Beverages', 'Beverages'), 
        ('Hot Apps', 'Hot Appetizers'),
        ('Cold Apps', 'Cold Appetizers'),
        ('Soup', 'Soup'),
        ('Seafood', 'Seafood'),
        ('Poultry', 'Poultry'),
        ('Beef', 'Beef'),
        ('Pork', 'Pork'),
        ('Vegetarian', 'Vegetarian'),
    )
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
print([a[0] for a in CATEGORIES]) # ['Beverages', 'Hot Apps', 'Cold Apps', 'Soup', 'Seafood', 'Poultry', 'Beef', 'Pork', 'Vegetarian']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example in a simple way:

```
for i in CATEGORIES:
  print(i[0]) #loop through the list and print out the first variable
```